# infix operator to pipe subprocess output to python function

Tags: python, xonsh

Can xonsh pipe subprocess output to a python function?

```
int($(ls|wc -l)) > 20
```

as

```
ls | wc -l  | int > 20
```

I can get close

```
from toolz import pipe
pipe($(ls |wc -l),int) > 20
```

this comes searching ways to port

```
# bash
[ $(ls |wc -l ) -gt 20 ] && echo busy dir
# xonsh
test @$(ls |wc -l)  '-gt' 20 and echo busy dir
# xonsh with more python 
len(`[^.].*`) > 20 and echo busy dir
```

But generally, I'm hoping for an infix operator a la [magrittr](http://magrittr.tidyverse.org/)'s forward pipe `%>%` or [coconut's](http://coconut-lang.org/) `|>`

Comment: this is an open issue on xonsh: https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/issues/1336

Answer (score 0, accepted):

coconut supports xonsh

> Coconut integrates with xonsh to allow the use of Coconut code directly from your command line. To use Coconut in xonsh, simply `pip install coconut` and then run `xontrib load coconut` from xonsh or add `xontrib load coconut` to your xonshrc file.

https://coconut.readthedocs.io/en/latest/DOCS.html#xonsh-support

Answer (score 1):

Someone did the trick in the github issue comment using sspipe, https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/issues/1336#issuecomment-502049121, but we can do it without it:

```
'Busy dir' if int($(ls | wc -l))>20 else ''
```

Comment: was hoping to find a way to make iterative prev history + pipe more ergonomic (try `ls`, then  `ls|wc -l`, then, in my fantasy, `ls|wc -l| > 20`) rather than having to jump around the line and track open/close parens (`ls |wc -l`, then `int($(ls | wc -l))>20` is trivial but still cumbersome)


total aside: looks like the sspipe code from the github issue is counting characters not files:
`ls | wc -l` ==  `88`; ` len(`[^.].*`)` == `88`;  `$(ls) | p(len)` == `1237`